# Code that worked in Uno is not working in Mega 2560

Tags: arduino-mega

I send data with Android and read it from the Arduino serial screen. When I use UNO, I can read the data smoothly. When I use MEGA, it uploads the code without error, but does not transfer data on the serial screen. Can you tell me why?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial bluetooth(2,3);    // TX,RX                               
int bar_analog=0;                                    
int head_analog=0;
int bar_anim=0;
int strip_anim=0;
int motor_speed=1;
int direct=0;
int level=0;
boolean debug = true;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);                              
  bluetooth.begin(9600);                           
  Serial.println("Program is starting...");              
  Serial.println("by Berke Ogulcan Parlak");    
}

void loop() {
  if (bluetooth.available()) {
    while (bluetooth.available())                    
    {                                                
      bar_analog = bluetooth.parseInt();              
      head_analog = bluetooth.parseInt();
      bar_anim = bluetooth.parseInt();
      strip_anim = bluetooth.parseInt();
      motor_speed = bluetooth.parseInt();
      direct = bluetooth.parseInt();
      level = bluetooth.parseInt();
      if (debug) {                                  
        Serial.print("Bar Brightness: ");                        
        Serial.println(bar_analog);
        Serial.print("Bar Animation Type: ");
        Serial.println(bar_anim);
        Serial.print("Headlight Brightness: ");
        Serial.println(head_analog);
        Serial.print("Strip Animation Type: ");
        Serial.println(strip_anim);
        Serial.print("Motor Speed Level: ");
        Serial.println(motor_speed);
        Serial.print("Direction: ");
        Serial.println(direct);
        Serial.print("Mast Goes: ");
        Serial.println(level);
        Serial.println("--------------------------------");
      }
      if (bluetooth.read() == '\n') {
        azdırma işlemleri bu satırda yapılacak..

      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

SoftwareSerial relies on the Pin Change interrupt. Not all pins on the Mega have pin change interrupts.

But that is all a moot point really, because when you're using a microcontroller that has lots of *real hardware UARTs* there is no call to be using SoftwareSerial in any case.